# VB.net Same Data Splitting Differently Between Browser Control Scrape and Webrequest

Tags: vb.net, webrequest, scrape

So I have a browser control in vb.net open, scrape table lines and then parse the data up by splitting on environment.newline.

I load the same site with a webrequest and the data is there (not hidden behind JS or anything) and the row scrapes with the same data but without the line breaks in between this time.

Little puzzled by this one. I've searched around and the only related thing I saw was that the encoding for a webrequest defaults to UTF-8 but the top of the page I'm trying to read is:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

So I'm really not sure why there would be a difference between what the browser is seeing and what the webrequest is seeing.

Browser scrape:

```
 For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.Bookie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
                If element.GetAttribute("class") = "row" Then
```

Which works great.

The WebRequest scrape:

```
For Each node As HtmlNode In SmarkDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='row']")
```

Reads the same data but seems to ignore the line breaks.

The string split is the same syntax not removing line breaks or anything and as far as I'm aware there's no option in the webrequest to include/exclude them.

I'd appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the WebRequest not ignore line breaks? I'm not really sure what the specific question is.

Comment: Webbrowser is a browser, webrequest is not. A browser can parse and interpret HTML, and e.g. normalize new lines. Webrequest does not parse anything. If `SmarkDocument` comes from HtmlAgilityPack, then it is the pack that does the parsing, and it can have different rules for normalizing line breaks (e.g. normalize them to single LF characters as opposed to CRLF, so they will no longer match `environment.newline`).